Readable and conventional way to fill in nil/non-nil only parameters
Some functions require a list of parameters that only tell the difference based on nil or non-nil. Is there a way to fill such parameters in a readable and conventional way?
For example, add-hook accepts 2 optional parameters. The 4th parameter, local, only makes a difference if it is nil or non-nil. If I have to fill in the 4th parameter with non-nil, I can do:
(add-hook some-mode-hook #'my-hook-func 100 t)

From a readability perspective, this t is obscure. I can do the following instead:
(add-hook some-mode-hook #'my-hook-func 100 'local)
(add-hook some-mode-hook #'my-hook-func 100 :local)
(add-hook some-mode-hook #'my-hook-func 100 "local")

Which way is considered conventional?
This question asks about what way is conventional. A convention is well-established practice. This is not a poll collecting question. It doesn't ask what is the most readable or what you like most. While there may be more than one answer, it isn't opinion-based.
Before you vote to close, please check out the elisp-conventions tag: Asking about conventions doesn't mean it's opinion-based. If there's no convention, instead of closing this question, consider answering no convention with support material.

This is a bad example: the depth argument in add-hook is not a two-valued argument, so you should never specify it as t or nil. Instead, it is an integer with values between -100 and 100. If not speficied, it gets a default value of 0. Read the doc string of the function - note that it says: For backward compatibility reasons, a symbol other than nil is interpreted as a DEPTH of 90. That is highly non-obvious and you should never use that: specifying it as t or any of the others is not only not readable, it is an invitation for bugs to creep in.

@NickD Sorry for the confusion, I intended to say local is nil or non-nil. For some reason I messed up when I typed the question.

Functions defined with defun support only positional arguments. If you want keyword arguments (like f(local=True) in Python, or f({'local': true}) in EMCAScript), use cl-defun. However, you can't change the existing behavior of add-hook anyway...

The question IS opinion-based: what is "conventional" varies between groups of programmers (and in many cases, between programmers in the same group). You may find that core Emacs code e.g. follows different conventions than the code of an external package. In my opinion (formed by reading random bits of Emacs core code, large swaths of Org mode code and more random bits of package code), the t/nil convention is the "most" conventional, followed by the symbol convention, where you write 'foo because the doc string of the function names the corresponding parameter foo...

... and that's a distant second place. The :foo convention is too confusing: it is used primarily in property lists, so you don't want to use it here. Despite @shynur's preference, using a string is not common AFAICT.

@NickD: I have the same question as OP before.  t or nil is not very intuitive, and symbols like 'foo or :bar may populate the obarray thus slow down the symbol search.  So I finally chose string.

t or nil is not very intuitive - agreed, but it at least tells you that the function expects something with two values; using a string does not. The only remedy is to read the doc string - every time you use the function or until it has become part of your finger memory (but in that case, watch out for incompatible changes). The doc string is the only way I know to be absolutely sure and Emacs makes it easy to see it. My memory was never particularly good and in my dotage it's gotten worse, but I will never forget C-h f. I remember not the information itself, but how to find it.

@NickD If you see t/nil as the convention, that can go to an answer...

Are we having an opinion poll? As I said, that (i.e. t/nil being most prevalent) is my perception, but I have no idea whether my perception is congruent to "reality" (however we define that), so if that's the kind of answer you are seeking, it is necessarily opinion-based. I voted to close your question as opinion-based, and that was my argument for it being opinion-based, so it would be hypocritical of me to provide the comment as an answer.

See the coding conventions section in the Elisp Ref manual, e.g.: there is no mention of this at all. As for the tag, there is no usage guidance for it: whether the other 17 questions under it are opinion-based, I don't know; but that is no argument for this question being opinion-based or not.

There's no official convention about such a style concern. There are no common unofficial "conventions" about that either. Anyone can think what they prefer corresponds to some shared style/convention. The question definitely encourages opinion-based answers. It's a reasonable, and perhaps productive, question for a discussion site, such as Reddit. (Perhaps productive in terms of developing ideas and consensus - not just a survey/poll.)

@Drew I think it's a good answer. A convention is about an established consensus, and I'm asking what this consensus is. This question is not collecting opinions and reaching a consensus. If there's no such convention, the answer is "no". And you have given citations and references, which is a perfectly objective answer.

@NickD You have cited a formal document about "conventions that you should follow", yet you claim this question is opinion-based. I requested readers to check the other convention tagged questions just as examples to help understand, they are not a formal part of an argument.

Yes, because this question is not addressed by that document (or any other document I know of). We are having a discussion about this in the comments here and that's not what  comments are about( they are about clarifying the question): the reason for that is that your question invites answers that are opinion-based and is therefore unsuitable for this forum. @Drew suggested r/emacs on Reddit as a suitable forum. The Emacs help mailing list might be another. But SE Emacs is not. In any case, that's my opinion: if people disagree, nothing happens.

For readability, I recommend use a string as a placeholder explicitly:
(add-hook some-mode-hook #'my-hook-func
          100 "buffer local")

I observe this style since long time ago.

Please fix your answer to at least agree with the doc string of add-hook, As it stands, it's wrong (although I understand that the OP's original version  of the question probably threw you off).

"try to make sense of what you wrote" - my bad... I mistook the position of the formal parameters

This doesn't say anything about any conventions.

No, it isn’t conventional. You’ll get a lot of strange looks if you show that code to people. For one thing, it looks exactly like you are passing in keyword arguments, and the way those are read would make the depth be 100.
